# scala protected modifier convert to java class is public

Tags: scala

In a scala class, I have defined a protected field and a protected method:

TestProtected.scala:

```
class TestProtected {
  protected var f = 0

  protected def m = 1
}
```

In my opinion, it will convert the protected f and m to a java protected filed and method. But when i use jd-gui to decompiler the TestProtected.class to java file, the result was beyond my expectation:

```
@ScalaSignature(bytes="...")
public class TestProtected
{
  private int f= 0;

  public int f() { return this.f; } 
  public void f$eq(int x$1) { this.f = x$1; } 
  public int m() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

The f and m in java file is public?

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably linked to the fact that `protected` in Scala [doesn't](http://daily-scala.blogspot.fr/2009/11/access-modifiers-public-private.html) mean the same thing as in Java, but I can't put the pieces together.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, **Scala** `protected` is different from **Java** `protected`:

**Java**'s `protected` is visible to **same package** and **subclass**, **Scala** `protect` is only visible to *subclass*, so *Scala*'s `protected` is more restrictive than *Java*'s.

So this is caused by `JVM Level` access modifier is not same as **Scala** access modifier, we know **Scala** runs on `JVM`, for running on `JVM`, it needs to generate the compatible **byte code** in `JVM`.

There are some other example like:

```
private
private[this]
private[package]
```

There are some reference about **Scala Access**:

[Protected and private in Scala become public in Java](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/11418)

[Scala Access](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-scala07298/index.html)

[Protected Members](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/packages-and-imports.html#13.4)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but this may be because companion object of a class should also be able to access protected members of a class in scala. And because companion object is actually a different class from its companioin class, scala has to compile `protected` members to `public` in a bytecode.